# How to install an apk on my Emulator if I get: Snapshot storage already in use?

Tags: android

This is the error message I have met when I run my app, and my logcat is empty

```
    -08-09 11:19:22 - TestCity] ------------------------------
[2011-08-09 11:19:22 - TestCity] Android Launch!
[2011-08-09 11:19:22 - TestCity] adb is running normally.
[2011-08-09 11:19:22 - TestCity] Performing com.pack.android.TestCityActivity activity launch
[2011-08-09 11:19:22 - TestCity] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'my_device'
[2011-08-09 11:19:22 - TestCity] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_device'
[2011-08-09 11:19:24 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2011-08-09 11:19:24 - Emulator] ko:Snapshot storage already in use: C:\Documents and Settings\Ram\.android\avd\my_device.avd/snapshots.img
```

Comment: if you are using eclipse, then go to AVD manager and before starting your emulator select checkBox with option "wipe User Data " and then say ok

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. Turned out to be caused (in part) by leftover lock files from a previous run (which may explain why ntc's 'wipe user data' fix didn't work for me).

Look in the folder shown in the error message (that is, without the snapshots.img bit).
You should see several folders ending in .lock

each folder may contain a file called 'pid'. If so, delete the 'pid' files. 
That allows the emulator to start, but it stuck at the plain text 'android' stage,
so I deleted the various .img files and tried again and the emulator started OK.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem. I Just deleted all *.lock folder and the AVD started fine.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the Built-in (type of emulator) is the same in your Graphical Layout. You should configure the same type (but version can be different).

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill your ADB-server using `adb kill-server`

Then restart your server. More info over [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html)

If all fails, create a new AVD.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse ADT, just press 'Clean...' from Project menu. Then run again. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

just kill avd process from task manager and restart your eclipse.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of exactly what they're intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. This is especially true for answers that involve killing processes.